# Custom registration field to SQL database

Tags: filters, users, actions, forms, user-registration

I have created new columns in a SQL table called `wp_users`. Those fields are "giodo", "handel" and "regulamin".

What I want to do is to add '1' to each column when a user registers and selects corresponding checkboxes.

I added checkboxes to the form using form_register and then I added those checkboxes to user data with this (here is an example for only one of them):

```
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');
function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['giodo'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'giodo', $_POST['giodo']);
}
```

Can I somehow add their values to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created new colums in a SQL table 'wp_users'. Those fields are
>   "giodo", "handel" and "regulamin".

Don't add columns to Core tables. There is no guarantee that these won't be destroyed or corrupted on next update. What you should be using is *user meta*, and in fact that appears to be what you are actually using:

```
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');
function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['giodo'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'giodo', $_POST['giodo']);
}
```

So the question is a bit confusing.

Your code *should have already* inserted data into the database, just not where you are trying to put it. Your code should have inserted the data into the `$wpdb->usermeta` table and can be retrieved using [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta). That is what I would suggest. Abandon the attempt to add columns to a Core table and use the user meta API, which is what it was built for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I find it hard seeing which meta piece is which. I used two foreach statements to echo out this data and there are no labels alongside those echoed pieces. Could you tell me how to make a distinction between them? Is there a function to put labels on this echoed meta data?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. `get_user_meta()` without a specified key will give you an associative array. With a key... well, you already know what the key is.

Comment: (Sorry for the formatting, I don't know how to change it in the comments)

Hmmm I did this:

`$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$arrays_globusy = get_user_meta($current_user->id);
$x = 0;
foreach ($arrays_globusy as $key => $value) {
   echo $key.": ".$value." <br>";
 }
`
and this is what I got:

`first_name: Array
last_name: Array
nickname: Array
description: Array
rich_editing: Array
comment_shortcuts: Array
admin_color: Array
use_ssl: Array
show_admin_bar_front: Array
wp_capabilities: Array
wp_user_level: Array`

Comment: `var_dump($arrays_globusy);` and spend a few minutes reading this: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Okay I will commit myself to it :). Thank you for yuour help.